# how to arrange the checkboxes in 3/3 format on a layout of a form

Tags: php, html, css

Hi there. Can anyone please tell me how to arrange the list of checkboxes of cuisines label which is retrieved from the data base and when it is displaying it is not in the order coming side by side all together I want it to be displayed in a 3 by 3 format. Here is the code for that:

```
<div id="frmform">
    <form name="frmrestaurant" id="frmrestaurant" method="post" onsubmit="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p class="msgsignup">Add Restaurant</p>
  <div id="iderror"></div>
  <div class="topinputs">
   <div> <label for="restaurant_name" class="name">Restaurant Name :</label><input type="text" name="restaurant_name" size="32" id="restaurant_name" value="<?php echo $row->restaurant_name; ?>" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] text-input" />  </div>


   </div>
   <div> <label for="website" class="name">Website :</label><input  size="32" type="text" name="website" id="website" value="<?php echo $row->website; ?>" class="validate[required,length[0,100]] text-input" />  </div>
   <div> <label for="budget" class="name">Budget :</label>
   <?php echo $this->lists['budget'];?>
   </div>
   <div> <label for="idcuisine" class="cuisine"  >Cuisine:</label>
   <?php echo $this->lists['cuisine']  ;?> 

   <div> <label for="idcategory" class="category">Category:</label>
   <?php echo $this->lists['category'];?>
   </div>
```

The lists of cuisine and category is not displaying properly.

Thanks.

Comment: <div> <label for="idcuisine" class="cuisine"  >Cuisine:</label>
   <?php echo $this->lists['cuisine']  ;?> 
   
   <div> <label for="idcategory" class="category">Category:</label>
   <?php echo $this->lists['category'];?>
how to format the checkboxes of these lists

Answer (score 2):

It could be done with php right logic

```
    <tr>
        <?php 
             while($ofetch=$db->fetchNextObject($query)) 
              { 
              $j++;
        ?>
                 <td width="33%">
                  <input type="checkbox" name="service[]" id="service" value="<?php echo $ofetch->service_id?>" /> some text
                 </td>
                 <?php if($j%3==0) { echo "</tr><tr>";}
                   }
                   ?>
   </tr>
```